# Ionic List from Object

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Please can you help me to display data from an object in a List.
My hard coded Test data works fine, but as soon as I replace it with the dynamic object data I receive from my cordova contacts plugin all list items become [object object]

**contacts.ts**

```
export class ContactsPage {
ladder: any;
contactsfound = [];
search = false;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private contacts: Contacts) {
//prepoulated with test data
this.ladder = [
        'Adelaide',
        'Collingwood',
        'Essendon',
    ];
}
ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad ContactsPage');
this.findfn();
}
findfn() {
    let fields:ContactFieldType[] = ['name'];
    //Display Test data 
    this.ladder = this.contacts.find(fields);
    //Replace Test data with object property name received from cordova plugin contacts.find  
    this.contacts.find(['name'], {filter: "", multiple: true})
                 .then(data => {
                 this.ladder = data
    });
  }
}
```

**contacts.html** looks like this

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list reorder="true" (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let team of ladder; let i = index;">{{i+1}}. {{team}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you please try in html {{ladder | json}} before ion-list?

Comment: What does `this.contact.find()` return ? Try `console.log(data)` to debug it.

Comment: That's my problem, I actually don't know. The reason is contacts is a cordova plugin that only works on an actual mobile device. console.log is unavailable on a real device. Any suggestions on how I can guess the structue? eg data[0][0] (ps I tried this - got blank records)

Comment: I'll give {{ladder | json}} a try

Comment: Thanks so much Paresh!
That was exactly what I needed. {{ladder | json}} displayed the structure of the object so that I could see what I was workig with. From that I was able to determine that the correct field name was ladder.displayName.